# How do I mount a virtual machine folder on a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to use docker containers as my development environment. 
I actually have created an ubuntu container with node.js and npm installed but I still don´t know howto share a folder between the host virtual linux machine (boot2docker coreOS) and this ubuntu container.
What I want is open the source code on my IDE but execute and run node from the container. Is even this a good practise? Do anyone develop using docker that way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share folder from your actual host OS, provided the boot2docker Linux VM has mounted some of those folders.

If that is the case, you can [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) a container specifying the host path mapped to the container path using volume.

```
docker run -v /host/folder:/container/folder
```